# I want to ensure a list of strings is sorted following a custom pattern

Tags: python

I want the list to be in this order ['PRE','IMP','POST','BO']

Where the actual list will have duplicates of each e.g.

Desired List

```
list = ['PRE', 'PRE', 'PRE','IMP', 'IMP','POST','BO', 'BO']
```

A possible out of order list:

```
list = ['IMP', 'PRE', 'PRE','IMP', 'IMP','POST','BO', 'BO']
```

I want to simply write code to check that the entire list follows the sequence order.

```
if list is in order:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Your edit suggests that you didn't read the duplicate, or understand how to apply it. Basically, `sorted(values, key=lambda x: {"PRE": 0, "IMP": 1, "POST": 2, "BO": 3}[x])`

Comment: The latter is the case, thank you!